# Rails 4: How can I get the value[id] of a selected item with collection_select in my form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-forms, collection-select

In my controller I would like to do the following:

```
class SubsController < ApplicationController

 def push_sub
    @sub = Sub.find(params[:id])
    @food = Food.find("ID of food selected from collection_select") => see my form down below
    @food.subs << @sub
  end

  private

    def sub_params
      params.require(:sub).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

@food.subs return an ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy like this for exemple:

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Sub id: 34, name: "Fake choco", description: "cacao fake", created_at: "2015-01-07 23:40:25", updated_at: "2015-01-07 23:40:25">, #<Sub id: 34, name: "Fake choco", description: "cacao fake", created_at: "2015-01-07 23:40:25", updated_at: "2015-01-07 23:40:25">, #<Sub id: 34, name: "Fake choco", description: "cacao fake", created_at: "2015-01-07 23:40:25", updated_at: "2015-01-07 23:40:25">]>
```

When clicking the f.submit in my form, it triggers the push_sub action which pushes a new @sub to the association of the selected item (@food).

I do not know how to get the ID of the selected Food in my form so that I can use it in my controller.

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @sub, :url => {:action => "push_sub"} do |f| %>

  <h1>What food is <%="#{@sub.name}"%> a substitute of?</h1>

  <div class="field">
    <%=collection_select(:sub, :foods, Food.all, :id, :name)%>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Happy new year to you all !

Antoine

### **UPDATE**

I have 3 models with a has_many through relationship: Food (eg: Chocolate), Sub (Chocolate food substitute), Joint (joint table).

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :joints
    has_many :subs, :through => :joints
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subs, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
class Sub < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :joints
    has_many :foods, :through => :joints
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :foods, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
class Joint < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :food
    belongs_to :sub
end
```

Comment: What is the association between Food and Substitute?

Comment: thanks for your time, I updated my question with my Models.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

I can iterate over the params in my controller like so:

```
   params[:sub].each do |k, v|
      @food_id = v
    end
```

So I can use @food_id to push a Sub to its active record collection proxy.